# Meaning of flags in PROCESS_EXTENDED_BASIC_INFORMATION struct?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, kernel

Can someone explain what all those bits stand for in `PROCESS_EXTENDED_BASIC_INFORMATION`?

```
typedef struct _PROCESS_EXTENDED_BASIC_INFORMATION {
    SIZE_T Size;    // Ignored as input, written with structure size on output
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION BasicInfo;
    union {
        ULONG Flags;
        struct {
            ULONG IsProtectedProcess : 1;
            ULONG IsWow64Process : 1;
            ULONG IsProcessDeleting : 1;
            ULONG IsCrossSessionCreate : 1;
            ULONG IsFrozen : 1;
            ULONG IsBackground : 1;
            ULONG IsStronglyNamed : 1;
            ULONG IsSecureProcess : 1;
            ULONG IsSubsystemProcess : 1;
            ULONG SpareBits : 23;
        } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
} PROCESS_EXTENDED_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PPROCESS_EXTENDED_BASIC_INFORMATION;
```

Microsoft showed this `struct` in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt809132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but gave no explanation for what those flags stand for.

Comment: The names of the bit flags are pretty clear. For instance, surely you can understand what IsWow64Process means.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Sure if you want me to list those that aren't clear for me. Here you go: `IsProtectedProcess`, `IsProcessDeleting`, `IsCrossSessionCreate`, `IsFrozen`, `IsBackground`, `IsStronglyNamed`, `IsSubsystemProcess`. Sorry if I'm the only one who doesn't know what those mean.

Comment: Well, `IsProtectedProcess` identifies a protected process, and so on. It's plain English. So the next question I suppose is what information you are looking for. And why you feel the answer can be found in this undocumented structure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You're a genius. And `IsFrozen` defines a frozen process, right?

Comment: By jove I think you are getting the hang of this. So, what information are you looking for. Asking for a definition of these 9 distinct process states is far too broad. What specific information are you looking for that led you to this structure?

Comment: Users have minimal access to protected processes; even debug privilege won't grant full access. Common examples are system processes such as smss.exe, csrss.exe, wininit.exe, and services.exe. A process will be in the deleting state once terminated (but not reaped yet since there's a handle). A cross-session create is when the parent process is in a different session -- commonly a session 0 service such as the task scheduler. A frozen process is suspended. UWP app packages can run in the background and are strongly named. NT subsystems have a server process, such as csrss.exe (per session).

Comment: `IsStronglyNamed` in my tests have all and only UWP apps, `IsFrozen` if process suspended (usual some UWP apps running in background, or process stopped under debugger). `IsCrossSessionCreate` if parent process run in another logon (not terminal) session. `IsBackground`, `IsSecureProcess`, `IsSubsystemProcess` - i never view in test. `IsProcessDeleting` - process already terminated, but somebody hold reference on it - so process object still exist. `IsProtectedProcess` - system protected process. `IsWow64Process` - think clear

Comment: @RbMm, when I create a Session 0 process as another user from Session 0, `IsCrossSessionCreate` is false, so it's unrelated to the logon session. In my tests, it's only true when the process is created in another terminal Session. A simple example is `psexec -si cmd`. Both the parent (psexesvc.exe in Session 0) and the child (cmd.exe in the active console Session) use the same SYSTEM logon session (0x3e7), but `IsCrossSessionCreate` is true for cmd.exe because it's in a different terminal Session from the parent.

Comment: @eryksun - i have another result. `IsCrossSessionCreate` exactly when parent run in another logon session. say for example when we exec from not elevated (explorer) elevated process. if want you can test with [this](https://www.sendspace.com/file/1mr8gj) - here 2 my utilities. which show `PROCESS_EXTENDED_BASIC_INFORMATION` for all processes in system(+some additional info). another tool like sysinternal utilit for show logon sessions, but with fixed errors and more info

Comment: @eryksun so simplest way got `IsCrossSessionCreate` - run as admin program from explorer. say notepad or regedit. and it will be have `IsCrossSessionCreate`

Comment: @RbMm, elevating makes a remote procedure call to the Application Information service in Session 0, which calls `CreateProcessAsUser` and fakes the parent process via `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS`.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, of course. but i mean under parent process not creator, but exactly inherited from process. so creator will be svchost, but inherited from (via PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS) however explorer

Comment: I take back my comment about `IsSubsystemProcess` however. I thought that was obviously from the `SubsystemProcess` in the `EPROCESS` structure, which is true only for instances of csrss.exe, which makes perfect sense. But I disabled the protection on it; queried `PROCESS_EXTENDED_BASIC_INFORMATION`; and was surprised to see that `IsSubsystemProcess` wasn't set, so I have no idea what this flag means, other than that the name is misleading.

Comment: @RbMm, but what matters is that the real parent is the Appinfo service in Session 0. It seems the `EPROCESS` `CrossSessionCreate` flag is set early on and not affected by `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS`. ISTM, that's the only explanation for what I observe otherwise when creating across *terminal* sessions using the same SYSTEM logon session (ID 0x3e7). If it were just a matter of the logon session, then `CrossSessionCreate` would be false in those cases.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, you absolute right and i mistake here. really `IsCrossSessionCreate` related to terminal sessions. check now this (create notepad in 0 session from elevated tool). both processes run in same logon session, but in different terminal (0 and 1) and notepad have `IsCrossSessionCreate` set

Comment: Thank you, @RbMm and eryksun for the info. That's an interesting discussion.

Comment: @eryksun: I'm curious, guys, is `IsProtectedProcess` bit the same what is returned by [ZwQueryInformationProcess(ProcessBreakOnTermination)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687420(v=vs.85).aspx) call or a newer [IsProcessCritical()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn386160(v=vs.85).aspx) API?

Answer (score 3):

The following is a *highly undocumented* stuff that Microsoft probably doesn't want you to use. Do so at your own risk.

*PS. But, you actually had an interesting question. So just for general education:*

- **IsProtectedProcess** (0x001) System protected process: other processes can't read/write its VM or inject a remote thread into it. (Old style. If I'm not mistaking, it was available since XP SP3.)
- **IsWow64Process** (0x002) [WOW64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139(v=vs.85).aspx) process, or 32-bit process running on a 64-bit Windows.
- **IsProcessDeleting** (0x004) Process was terminated, but there're open handles to it -- a very transient stage. *(That should be of any interest to you only if you're a kernel driver.)*
- **IsCrossSessionCreate** (0x008) Process was created across terminal sessions. *Ex: Read [CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx) for details.*
- **IsFrozen** (0x010) [Immersive process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448383(v=vs.85).aspx) is suspended (applies only to UWP processes.) For example, Immersive process can be suspended if a user moves it to the background or minimizes it. Used mostly for power saving. [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-suspend-resume#suspend).
- **IsBackground** (0x020) Immersive process is in the Background task mode. UWP process may temporarily switch into performing a [background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/guidelines-for-background-tasks). Used mostly for power saving.
- **IsStronglyNamed** (0x040) UWP Strongly named process. The UWP package is digitally signed. Any modifications to files inside the package can be tracked. *This usually means that if the package signature is broken the UWP app will not start.*
- **IsSecureProcess** (0x080) [Isolated User Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt809132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) process -- new security mode in Windows 10, with more stringent restrictions on what can "tap" into this process.
- **IsSubsystemProcess** (0x100) Set when the type of the process subsystem is other than Win32 (like *NIX, such as Ubuntu.) Yes, you read it right, you can [run Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) natively on Windows 10. ([Ref1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559960(v=vs.85).aspx), [Ref2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt805892(v=vs.85).aspx).)

*PS2. I'm open for corrections, if any ...*

Comment: Protected processes were [added in Vista](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46ed60f1-e02c-48db-9eba-eddbd106d54f) as a way to restrict access that even the debug privilege can't sidestep. The system was extended to Protected Light processes (PPL) in Windows 8, which introduces signer levels of protection: None, Authenticode, CodeGen, Antimalware, Lsa, Windows, WinTcb, WinSystem, and App. Generally a process running at a higher signer level dominates a process at a lower level. A protected process also restricts DLL loading based on the process `SignatureLevel`.