What does the Background field in the EPROCESS structure mean on Windows?
I am trying to understand the meaning of the Background field in the EPROCESS structure on Windows. I attempted to retrieve this field using the following code:
NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, ppebi, sizeof(PROCESS_EXTENDED_BASIC_INFORMATION), NULL);

However, I found that the Background field is always set to 0 for all processes on my Windows system. Why is this happening? What is the significance of this field?
I expected the Background field to vary for different processes, but it is always 0. I am looking for an explanation of what this field represents and why it is always 0 on my system.
Windows version

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47347441/179634
